# Graph getting hidden while zooming in ( using the zoom scroll bar )

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using HighChart's stock chart. The chart is rendering correctly. But, while zooming in my graph line alone is getting hidden. But, when I am moving back to the last position the graph is displaying correctly.

Please guide me to resolve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wqm6sdvz/ Sample work around ( with issue )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are providing the data array that is not sorted as you can see in the Highcharts error - https://www.highcharts.com/errors/15. So, the solution is to sort data. Check the demo posted below.

**Code:**

```
Highcharts.StockChart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container1',
    zoomType: 'x'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'AAPL',
    data: [
      [1556881096000, 3],
      [1556881096000, 3],
      [1556881096000, 3],
      [1556881096000, 3],
      [1556880496000, 3],
      [1556880496000, 3],
      [1556880496000, 3],
      [1556880496000, 3],
      [1556879896000, 9],
      [1556879896000, 9]
    ].sort()
  }]
});
```

**Demo:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n2bLro7g/3/

Comment: can i know is there any specific way to find out this issue or how you got this issue. If you tell me, its more support for my future. Thanks !

Comment: I've debugged it and find out that this approach needs an array of points. Synchronized charts are a custom example of using Highcharts library.

Comment: Thanks for the support